# JDBC PreparedStatement: How to add a Composite Type

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement, composite-types

How do you add a PostgreSQL Composite Type by means of a `PreparedStatement`?
The composite type is:

```
CREATE TYPE fullcontact AS (address address,contacts contact);
ALTER TYPE fullcontact OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON TYPE fullcontact IS 'Describe a type for a contact info with phone, email, and  address';
```

I am trying to add it via

```
FullContact fc = (FullContact)value;
PGobject pgObj = castToPGObject(fc);
PreparedStatement st = [this is a reference i obtain from a method];
st.setObject(index,pgObj);
```

The `castToPGObject` converts the `FullContact` instance to the ROW format. This is the result of the conversion of one instance:

```
ROW(ROW('Italy','Country',null,10,'1202'),ROW('email','aPhone','aMobile',null))
```

Used with an INSERT it works like a charm, but when I try to use `PreparedStatement` it fails. 
I have looked at the code of the JDBC Driver and it seems that the STRUCT type of PostgreSQL is not supported. Am i missing something?

From `setObject` I obtain that instead of the right conversion `PreparedStatement` adds `'` where it  shouldn't. E.g., instead of the ROW above I obtain:

```
'ROW(ROW(''Italy'',''Country'',null,10,''1202''),ROW(''email'',''aPhone'',''aMobile'',null))'
```

And this fails because it is not recognized as a Struct any more. I have tried also by adding

```
st.setEscapeProcessing(false);
```

but the `'` are still added. I need to use `PreparedStatement` because of a problem I have inside Hibernate when defining a custom usertype.
I am thinking about joining the JDBC Driver project to try to add support for STRUCT object.

Answer (score 1):

The row constructor `ROW()` is a PostgreSQL **function call**. You need to pass a **value** - or to be precise: a string literal representing the composite type.

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT '("(Italy,""Country with space"",,10,1202)"
        ,"(email,aPhone,aMobile,)")'::fullcontact
```

So your value would be:

```
("(Italy,""Country with space"",,10,1202)","(email,aPhone,aMobile,)")
```

I put in 'Country with space' to demonstrate the syntax with special characters.
Read the details about [**composite value input** in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html#AEN7228).

Comment: Sorry...the problem is not on the SQL itself but on the use of the prepared statement that doesn't give me the opportunity to set a struct type...I mean that when I add the right string an escape occurs giving me the wrong result that I have reported on my question...on Monday I'll try to publish a complete example...however thank you for your support and your correction on the language ;-)